# What are the different use cases for APITestCase, APISImpleTestCase, and APITransactionTestCase in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, api, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

The docs for the different test case classes are [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/)

I am unsure of what situations I would use each of the test case classes:

- APITestCase
- APISimpleTestCase
- APITransactionTestCase

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As explained in the [Django Rest Framework Docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#test-cases), the 3 available test classes simply extend the regular Django test classes but switch the client to use `APIClient`.

This can also be seen in the Django Rest Framework source code

```
class APITransactionTestCase(testcases.TransactionTestCase):
    client_class = APIClient


class APITestCase(testcases.TestCase):
    client_class = APIClient


class APISimpleTestCase(testcases.SimpleTestCase):
    client_class = APIClient
```

The first test case you should know about is the `APISimpleTestCase` which allows us to test general DRF/Django things such as http redirects and checking some callable raises an exception. The docs note that we shouldn't use `APISimpleTestCase` when doing any testing with the database.

The reason we shouldn't use `APISimpleTestCase` with the database is because the test data would stay in the database across multiple tests. To get around this we must use `APITransactionTestCase` which will use `atomic()` blocks to wrap tests in transactions and allow the test runner to roll back the database at the beginning of each test, allowing easy atomic testing of database related actions. It also adds some extra assertion methods related to database assertions such as `assertNumQueries`.

Finally, the `APITestCase` wraps the tests with 2 `atomic()` blocks, one for the whole test class and one for each test within the class. This essentially stops tests from altering the database for other tests as the transactions are rolled back at the end of each test. By having this second `atomic()` block around the whole test class, specific database transaction behaviour can be hard to test and hence you'd want to drop back to using `APITransactionTestCase`.

Comment: APITransactionTestCase does not use atomic() blocks to wrap tests. It uses truncation get rid of the changes after the test. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/tools/#transactiontestcase